# How to Write multiple Arrays in excel using Matlab

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab

I have list of values save in variables like. `A= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and `B = 4,5,6,73,2,3,2`  //This may be Array or column. Easy one will be preffered

**Note** A and B values will be dynamic which will be get through some function.

I want to save A's and B's Values in Excel Sheet, like A's values in First column  and B's values in 2nd Column.

I read about `xlswrite` but did not find any scenerio as i require.

And when They are saved then Again want to read them, and to save them in some other variables like `C` and `D`. I want to save Data of first column in C and second column data in D.

I read about `C = xlsread('filename')` but problem with it is. This save all the values in one variable. like if Excell have two columns. Those both will be saved in one variable C. But my requirment is one colum in one varibale and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html)

**Syntax** for writing to excel file

> xlswrite(filename,A,sheet,xlRange)

**Code:**

```
%// As your variable is a row vector, it is transposed to column vector
%// before writing, as you preferred    
xlswrite('outputFileName.xlsx',[A.',B.'],1,'D2')
```

<sup>Note: Make sure that the excel file is closed while writing</sup>

**Syntax** for reading from excel file

> num = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange)

**Code:**

```
%// reading the range into one temporary variable
temp = xlsread('outputFileName.xlsx',1,'D2:E7')
C = temp(:,1)
D = temp(:,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know English is not your primary language, but please try to be as gramatically correct as you can, it will make your questions easier to understand, and easier to answer to.

As for your question, I think you want to use the additional parameter in the functions you found to specify the columns you are writing to:

```
xlswrite('sheet.xls', A, 'E3')
```

will write the data of A on the cells E3, ..., E9.

And when you want to retrieve it, you do the same:

```
C = xlsread('sheet.xls', 'E3-E9')
```

This will read E3 to E9 cells and put the value in C.

Comment: At the same time i want to write two varibales (A,B) data in one sheet. A data in column 1 and B's data in Column 2.